# ERROR: The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios

I'm getting this error "The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier" after my application successfully compiles.This error prevents my game from launching on the phone or the simulator. I have no idea how to fix this as I was following this tutorial [How To Make A Space Shooter iPhone Game](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3611/how-to-make-a-space-shooter-iphone-game) using Cocos2d.

Answer (score 1):

This could be because the bundle identifier has invalid characters in it or no characters in it. The bundle identifier is found in the Info.plist file.

This is what constitues a valid application bundle identifier:

> The bundle identifier string
>   identifies your application to the
>   system. This string must be a uniform
>   type identifier (UTI) that contains
>   only alphanumeric (A-Z,a-z,0-9),
>   hyphen (-), and period (.) characters.
>   The string should also be in
>   reverse-DNS format. For example, if
>   your company’s domain is Ajax.com and
>   you create an application named Hello,
>   you could assign the string
>   com.Ajax.Hello as your application’s
>   bundle identifier. The bundle
>   identifier is used in validating the
>   application signature.
>   [source (apple developer)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1)

This may also be of use:

> An identifier used by iOS and Mac OS X
>   to recognize any future updates to
>   your app. Your Bundle ID must be
>   registered with Apple and unique to
>   your app. Bundle IDs are app-type
>   specific (either iOS or Mac OS X). The
>   same Bundle ID cannot be used for both
>   iOS and Mac OS X apps.
>   [source](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)